# Why was Agni eulogised as Lord of slayers of VRITRA in Rig Veda III.16.1?

Tags: rig-veda, indra, agni, vritra

Rig Veda [III.16.1](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv03016.htm), dedicated to ***AGNI***, says:

> ayamaghniḥ suvīryasyeśe mahaḥ saubhaghasya | rāya īśe svapatyasya
>   ghomata īśe vṛtrahathānām ||

The translation of this mantra by [H.H. Wilson](http://vedicheritage.gov.in/flipbook/Rigveda_Samhita_Eng_Vol_III/#book/37)(P.12) is as follows:

> This AGNI is the lord of heroism and of great good fortune; he is the
>   lord of wealth comprising progeny and cattle; he is ***the  Lord of
>   slayers of VRITRA***

In Rig Veda it was mentioned at many places that Indra eliminated [VRITRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vritra).

In the mantra in question,  it was mentioned that AGNI was ***the  Lord of
slayers of VRITRA***.  Please note that it was mentioned as ***slayers of VRITRA*** and that AGNI was eulogised as Lord of ***slayers of VRITRA***.  In Rig Veda it was mentioned that VISHNU only assisted Indra in slaying VRITRA.

My questions are:

- Who are the other slayers of VRITRA, other than INDRA?
- Why was AGNI was eulogised  as **Lord** of slayers of VRITRA?

Comment: Wilson and Griffth are useless - not because they are "indologists" but because Rig Veda's highly abstruse Sanskrit was poorly understood in their time.  Here Vritra is "obstacle" not the snake/monster.  Brererton and Jamison is the gold standard from here on.@srimannarayana k v

Comment: Please post an answer, expressing your opinion @SK

Comment: I have no interest in this question - since I find Vrtra (a metaphorical concept) a more sympathetic figure than his enemies - Indra and Vishnu.  I just wanted to save you the trouble of using shoddy translations - ONLY use the gold standard - namely Brererton and Jamison https://www.academia.edu/30160889/Stephanie_W._Jamison_Joel_P._Brereton_The_Rigveda_3_Volume_Set_-_2014_.pdf - there might be good Hindi translations you can use for double checking. @srimannarayana k v

Comment: @SK: I have checked up the translation of Brererton and Jamison.  Agreed partially that Vritra indicates a type of obstacle, but not snake/monster, as commonly believed or understood.  This concept of obstacle , I am already aware of. The question was posted for a discussion on SPIRITUAL lines rather than on scholarly line and for the usage of general members.

Comment: Agni is an important God and this just seems normal henotheistic praise @srimannarayana k v  .  Vishnu's "parmam padam" is a theological foundation stone for vaishnavites, but Apam Napat also has a "paramam padam".  A lot of Rig Veda is just metaphorical poetry.

Comment: @SK: That is where the beauty of Rig Veda lies.  Given the fact that it was composed in such an intrinsic manner, its poetry put to many interpreters on a wrong scent.  Whether you call it henotheistic or monotheistic or something else, the Almighty fits into everything, like a loving father accepts the immature acts of the child :-)

Answer (score 1):

*वृत्र(Vritra)* is not an evil person or devil. Read the following meanings of the word in [Sanskrit Dictionary.](https://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0&direct=au&anz=100)

[image]

So *Vritra* is a word used for other things like *foe,enemy or stone*. Read other translations by **Griffith**.

> 1. THIS Agni is the Lord of great felicity and hero Strength; Lord of wealth in herds of kine; Lord of the battles with the **foe**.

Comment: I am aware of this aspect.  I am expecting a deeper meaning, especially for the phrase **īśe vṛtrahathānām**, which also translates to Lord of persons, who overcame obstacles or foes